# How to remove absolute value from inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

So I know that $|x| \le 2 \iff x\le 2 \text{ and } x \ge -2$.  But, I was wondering would the same rules apply for $|x+2| + |y| \le 5$. Would it be correct to say that this inequality is equivalent to $x + y \le 3 \text{ and }x + y \ge -7$?

Comment: `would the same rules apply` How would you apply the same rules? `Would it be correct to say that this inequality is equivalent to ...` No, why would it? Try $x=-7, y=0$ for example.

Comment: $|x| \leq 2$ if and only if $x \leq 2$ AND $x \geq -2$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The OP had it right in the original question, then that got mistakenly edited to "*or*" by someone else. Fixed now.

Comment: @user2325601 There is no point in changing the numbers in the question when a counterexample gets posted, unless you explain what your thinking is behind that.

Comment: @dxiv Reasoning behind it is clear unless you missed it in the original post. x + y +2 >= -5 thus x +y >=-7 it was an error of not changing the sign of the 2.

Comment: @user2325601 What's not clear is what you mean by `the same rules apply`, and how exactly you apply those `same rules` to come up with what follows. By the time you can explain that, and edit it into the question, you will have probably answered it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem involving two variables such as $$ |x+2| + |y| \le 5$$ you need to look at 4 regions in the $xy-plane$

1) $y\le 0$ and $x+2 \le 0$. In this region your inequality is $-(x+2)-y \le 5$

2) $y\le 0$and $x+2 \ge 0$. In this region your inequality is $(x+2)-y \le 5$

3) $y\ge 0$ and $x+2 \ge 0$. In this region your inequality is $(x+2)+y \le 5$

4) $y\ge 0$ and $x+2 \le 0$. In this region your inequality is $-(x+2)+y \le 5$

Answer (score 2):

Well, you decompose your inequality $|x+2| + |y| \le 5$ into intervals:

- $y<0 \implies |y| = -y$ and otherwise we have $|y|=y$
- $x<-2 \implies |x+2| = -(x+2)$ and otherwise $|x+2| = x+2$.

This gives you $2 \times 2 = 4$ interval ranges, each of which implies a different inequality.

Comment: In short, no; $|x + 2| + |y| \leq 5$ is *not* equivalent to $x + y \leq 3$ or $x + y\geq -3$ as statements.

Comment: Would I get $y<0$, $x<-2$, $y > -1$, $x > -3$, $-y-x>=2$ and $x+y=-2$